# Configure time zone to mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, my.cnf

I have a mysql 5.7 docker container. When I run the mysql command:

```
SELECT now();
```

It shows the time -3 hours to my current time (which is logical). I want to set the time zone in a config file. Following the documentation in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ I create a volume in my `docker-compose.yml` file like the following:

```
mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    container_name: mysql_container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/etc/mysql/custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
```

When I browse the files inside the container the file `custom.cnf` is there.
In that file, I tried some of the ways I found as solutions like:

```
[mysqld]
default_time_zone='Europe/Sofia'
```

or a compromise solution which is less elegant as the zone will have to be changed twice a year (summer / winter):

```
[mysqld]
default_time_zone='+03:00'
```

but none works. I have the sensation the this file is not loaded by mysql at all because if I try to put invalid configuration in there nothing happens either (the container starts normally).
Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587214/configure-timezone-in-dockerized-nginx-php-fpm/45587945#45587945?

Comment: It's not duplicate to that question. I don't want to set doker container's time, but prefer to set the mysql time in a .cnf file, just as I was able to do that with the PHP in it's .ini file.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So you need to use a `Dockerfile` in this case and handle it like below

```
FROM mysql:5.7.21
RUN echo "USE mysql;" > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/timezones.sql &&  mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo >> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/timezones.sql
```

This makes sure that when the mysql container loads it will load all the timezone info. Now you can use it using environment variables

**Environment variable**

```
mysqldb:
    #image: mysql:5.7.21
    build: .
    #container_name: mysql_container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - TZ=Europe/Sofia
```

To use it with a config file is a problem. When you start the DB it will give your an error

```
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.169214Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.215187Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.281229Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 2a87fec6-47bb-11e8-9f1e-0242ac110002.
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.284010Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.284404Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone 'Europe/Sofia'
mysqldb_1  | 2018-04-24T12:29:43.284567Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This is because it needs the timezone to have been already loaded. It is possible to fix this also, but too much of hassle. I will go with the environment variable only as that means when the container starts the timezone is already setup.

[image: Time]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, it works! I will be allowed to reward the bounty in "17 hours", and I will do. I wanted to have the most elegant and simple solution, because I am not an advanced linux user neither I am advanced in docker... but in this case I'll have some few new things to learn :)

Comment: After a lot of attempts, trying to bypass using a separate Dockerfile, I gave up and used the first solution which involves a Dockerfile built with docker-compose. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 12):

The `mariadb:10.3` docker container interprets the `TZ` environment variable, although it's not mentioned on the Readme.md for the docker image. In my case providing the value of `America\New_York` worked perfectly.

Comment: Yup, that worked for me too. It now mentions under the `MARIADB_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO` / `MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO` variable: "By default, the entrypoint script automatically loads the timezone data needed for the CONVERT_TZ() function. If it is not needed, any non-empty value disables timezone loading." so loading the tz data like in the accepted answer isn't necessary with recent mariadb images, and just setting the TZ variable is enough.

Answer (score 6):

value should be

```
default_time_zone=Europe/Sofia
```

[check details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone)

But this could give you error [like this](https://www.brucedev.com/posts/fatal-error-illegal-or-unknown-default-time-zone-in-mysql) while restarting the mysql service so you should use below command before editing custom.cnf file.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql -p
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, I'm using Keramatic https://kitematic.com configure by click on **MySQL** container **General** and add **TZ** specify with your current time show list in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

[image]
Cheers